# List all networks in android?

Tags: android

I am gonna to implement a application, to list all the networks and manually select one of them( similar to the stock one ), can some one what kind of api can I use or what documentation should I refer to , or any reference sites ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [`ConnectivityManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html)

> The primary responsibilities of this
>   class are to:
>
> - Monitor network connections (Wi-Fi, GPRS, UMTS, etc.)
> - Send broadcast intents when network connectivity changes
> - Attempt to "fail over" to another network when connectivity to a network
>     is lost
> - Provide an API that allows applications to query the
>     coarse-grained or fine-grained state
>     of the available networks

Get an instance of this class by calling:

`Context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you will have a look at NetworkInterface and its enumeration , too